# Unable to Import Data From Source From Azure DataLake with Power BI : Error Message 'Failed to save modifications to the server'

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake

I'm using the guide shown here to to Get Data from Azure Data Lake.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/tutorials/aas-lesson-2-get-data

Everything appears to be working fine. However, when I 'Import' from Power BI's Power Query Editor I get the message error message 'Failed to save modifications to the server'. I believe the underlying problem is the column 'Date Created' is Null, but I can't seem to delete the column.
I think the issue has something to do with Permissions, however I am the owner. I have include a few images to illustrate the problem.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Have you tried to change data types of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

**Cold and hard truth**: the issue you are encountering is not because of the date column you are highlighting. Its actually because of the data lake data source.

**Solution**: unfortunately once you have already created the data source, you cannot go back and change these settings, therefore you HAVE to delete the data source (and all of the tables that you have already created) and recreate it. When you get to the data lake url, put in a value for the "optional" field (I used 100000). And your issue should be resolved!

[highlighted is the optional (not really optional field)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onBpx.jpg)